# Call a callback after insert script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched for an answer, but i didn't find. I want to include the Nivo Slider script just if the screen is bigger than 768px. I have a function that creates a script tag just if the window size is bigger than 768px, then I call a function from this script.

```
    $(function(){

    (function(d, s, id){
        if(window.innerWidth > 768){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "plugins/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        }
    }(document, 'script', 'nivo'));

    });
```

Javascript calls the `nivoSlider()` method immediately after the script tag insert, but the script isn't loaded yet. It works if I put the nivo method inside of `setTimeout()`, but it's a crappy hack.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w3xh6/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `jQuery.getScript`: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
$.getScript('plugins/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js', function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
```

Or if you really want to go native:

```
js.onload = js.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = this.readyState;
  if( !this.loaded && ( !state || state=='loaded' || state=='complete' ) ) {
    this.loaded = 1;
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
  }
}
```

Comment: From the documentation it states "The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed." How can you guarantee the script has been executed when you call .nivoSlider()?

Comment: @Ceres That’s an interesting statement, but I have never ancountered a situation where the script delays it’s execution. I guess it’s more like a "disclaimer". I added a native onload so you can choose your poison.

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery, so use jQuery to load the script and use the success handler.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "plugins/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js",
  dataType: "script",
  cache : true,
  success: function() {
      $('#slider').nivoSlider();
  }
});
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that before? Thanks @epascarello, works fine to me.

Comment: @RGraham This is the same as getScript except getScript disables caching which is bad.

Comment: Caching is definitely not *bad*. Not versioning certainly *is* bad.

Comment: No it is bad because every request for the file is hitting the server!

Comment: Lol, I misread that as saying that `getScript` caches by default. Sorry :) I +1'd you anyway